# Eclipse Project Import/Export Issues

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to import a project into eclipse.  First time I imported into the workspace.  Then it had an error about `.classpath` was readonly.

So I decided not to import into my workspace but to access where it resides on svn.  So I tried to delete it.

Now when I import from another location it says it cannot be done because it exists in the workspace.  This eclipse problem has happened to me many times before. Do I need to manually remove the files from the workspace now?

More lunacy now the import project dialog cannot be closed!  It imported a tablet project and now says must click cancel (already done).  Way to go eclipse team!

Comment: Ok. Now I guess I have kill eclipse instance just to get out of the import dialog. Model dialog can't be done. Onto task manager.

Comment: I don't have time to file the bug but I've got a crazy situation here. The import dialog is telling me that I cannot import because project already exists, but its not allowing me to cancel. Yes, cancel is actually greyed out. I'm literally stuck now in the import/export dialog.

Comment: This must be a lunar eclipse!

Comment: This question should be upvoted guys! come on! I'm not the only one dealing with this eclipse nonesene.

Comment: Wizard cannot be closed due to an active operation. You must cancel the operation before you close the wizard.  Thanks Eclipse Team, just the informative message I needed.  Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Eclipse didn't do a clean delete for your project. Before trying to import it again, close (or kill) Eclipse and go to this folder:

```
<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects
```

Look for a folder from the previous project (should have the same name). If there is one, delete it. Also delete any remains of the project from the workspace itself and try doing the Import again.

Comment: I know that this happens to lots of folks.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  When you delete a project from Eclipse, it gives you the option of deleting the files from your workspace directory.  By default, it is not checked.

Comment: Well it is not clear if it is going to delete from the workspace or a location outside the workspace. I suppose it originally copied into workspace the delete would apply to what was in the workspace, but who is going to take that chance?